# Gradient descent versus finding where the gradient vanishes via solving systems of equations

Tags: systems-of-equations, machine-learning, numerical-optimization, gradient-descent

I started learning machine learning and got stuck at the following questions:

1. Why do we need to iterate the gradient descent algorithm?
2. Why don't we equate the gradient to zero and find all local minima?

Most likely, we can't reach the minimum; we can just come as close as possible and the learning rate controls how close. Am I right? Or do I miss something?

Sorry if this is a duplicate question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Generally speaking, finding where the gradient equals zero is only easy for quadratic cost functions. Solving systems of polynomial equations is not easy.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo, thanks for reply first of all!
but why we can't use Laplace transform in that case? I mean it could take much less computing time

Comment: Laplace transform? Where are the differential equations?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo, sorry, I might misunderstand you. 
I thought, that when we find a derivatives from MSE function, we are getting system of differential equations and in case it is difficult to solve it, we might use Laplace transform.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/23128/116107).

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was really helpful! Additionally thanks for showing how my question should look like!